# IIS 7 ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT only with public IP

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, iis-7, web-config

I'm working with WCF on IIS 7.

Previously, I have done a WCF library and set it to work on IIS 7. It works well, also if I use it with our public IP.

Then, I have done a WCF application and set it to work on the same IIS 7. The address is the same, the difference is in the port. This WCF works when I call it with the internal IP, but is I use the external IP, I get a timed out error.

You can try yourself, this is the pubblic address:

http://77.108.40.77:8096/

(if you put 8095 as port, it works).

Why am I getting this? (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)

This is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>

      <configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.``0, Culture=neutral, ``PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
   </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
  <service name="MultipayOnline.Service1" >
    <!--bindingConfiguration="SecurityByTransport"-->
    <!--<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecurityByTransport" name="base" contract="CardServiceLib.ICardService">-->

      <endpoint address="" name="base"
              behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="MultipayOnline.IMultiPOService" >
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SecurityByTransport" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="CorsSupport" type="WebHttpCors.CorsSupportBehaviorElement, WebHttpCors, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>


<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restBehavior">
      <!--<enableWebScript/>-->
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
      <CorsSupport />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" maxItemsInObjectGraph="123456" />
    </behavior>
    <!--<behavior name="customBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
      <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="true" maxItemsInObjectGraph="123456" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MultipayOnline.CustomPass, MultipayOnline"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>-->
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />


<protocolMapping>
  <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<!--
    Per sfogliare la directory radice dell'applicazione Web durante il debug, impostare il valore riportato sotto su true.
    Impostarlo su false prima della distribuzione per evitare di diffondere informazioni sulla cartella dell'applicazione Web.
  -->
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
<!--<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>-->
  </system.webServer>


  <connectionStrings><add name="isMultiPayOnLineEntities" connectionString="..." providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />    </connectionStrings>
```

Can you help me? Can I post something to you for make clearer the trouble?

Comment: Is that port open on your firewall / forwarded to the local computer on your router?

Comment: do you mean in the firewall of the iis server?

Comment: well, any firewall you have that's between the internet and that machine, really. also: it may be that local loop back is disallowed on your router, so you'll not be able to use the public IP to reference the machine from inside your network.

Comment: ok, i'm going to check this and give an update to you... meanwhile, if you have other hints.. :)

Comment: other hints, perhaps learn basic network troubleshooting? :)

Comment: well, sorry, but I don't do this usually.. so... I have some doubts!  I hope the fw is the answer... thank you for you patience

Comment: Yes, it was that.. sorry for the dumb question, if you write the answer I'll set it as solution! :)

Comment: I'm reading again this... ahah, this was like "ehi man, the is the plug connected?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your port is closed .Check your IP and Port in http://ping.eu/port-chk/ if its status is closed then this msg will be shown . Plz open this Port to solve this problem..